# How to do Laradock project deployment and workflow?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices, laradock

I'm quite new to Docker, and currently, very confused.

I'm trying to setup a dev environment using Laradock with the following containers:

1. laravel(workspace image);
2. php-fpm;
3. postgres;
4. pgadmin4;
5. python(still not done with config);
6. nginx.

This works well on my local machine(a Mac), but I have no Idea how to upload the project on a server(which is my goal). And also I want to develop on the "production" server to check out response times, etc.

I'm using **docker** and **docker-compose** for now.

docker-compose.yml parts:

```
workspace:
  build:
    context: ./workspace
    args:
      - LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION=${PHP_VERSION}
      - LARADOCK_PHALCON_VERSION=${PHALCON_VERSION}
      - INSTALL_SUBVERSION=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SUBVERSION}
      - INSTALL_XDEBUG=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_XDEBUG}
      - INSTALL_PHPDBG=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PHPDBG}
      - INSTALL_BLACKFIRE=${INSTALL_BLACKFIRE}
      - INSTALL_SSH2=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SSH2}
      - INSTALL_GMP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_GMP}
      - INSTALL_SOAP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SOAP}
      - INSTALL_LDAP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LDAP}
      - INSTALL_IMAP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IMAP}
      - INSTALL_MONGO=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MONGO}
      - INSTALL_AMQP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_AMQP}
      - INSTALL_PHPREDIS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PHPREDIS}
      - INSTALL_MSSQL=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MSSQL}
      - INSTALL_NODE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NODE}
      - NPM_REGISTRY=${WORKSPACE_NPM_REGISTRY}
      - INSTALL_YARN=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_YARN}
      - INSTALL_NPM_GULP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_GULP}
      - INSTALL_NPM_BOWER=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_BOWER}
      - INSTALL_NPM_VUE_CLI=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_VUE_CLI}
      - INSTALL_DRUSH=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DRUSH}
      - INSTALL_DRUPAL_CONSOLE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DRUPAL_CONSOLE}
      - INSTALL_AEROSPIKE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_AEROSPIKE}
      - AEROSPIKE_PHP_REPOSITORY=${AEROSPIKE_PHP_REPOSITORY}
      - INSTALL_V8JS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_V8JS}
      - COMPOSER_GLOBAL_INSTALL=${WORKSPACE_COMPOSER_GLOBAL_INSTALL}
      - COMPOSER_REPO_PACKAGIST=${WORKSPACE_COMPOSER_REPO_PACKAGIST}
      - INSTALL_WORKSPACE_SSH=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_WORKSPACE_SSH}
      - INSTALL_LARAVEL_ENVOY=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LARAVEL_ENVOY}
      - INSTALL_LARAVEL_INSTALLER=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LARAVEL_INSTALLER}
      - INSTALL_DEPLOYER=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DEPLOYER}
      - INSTALL_PRESTISSIMO=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PRESTISSIMO}
      - INSTALL_LINUXBREW=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LINUXBREW}
      - INSTALL_MC=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MC}
      - INSTALL_SYMFONY=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SYMFONY}
      - INSTALL_PYTHON=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PYTHON}
      - INSTALL_IMAGE_OPTIMIZERS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IMAGE_OPTIMIZERS}
      - INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK}
      - INSTALL_TERRAFORM=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_TERRAFORM}
      - INSTALL_DUSK_DEPS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DUSK_DEPS}
      - INSTALL_PG_CLIENT=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PG_CLIENT}
      - INSTALL_PHALCON=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PHALCON}
      - INSTALL_SWOOLE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SWOOLE}
      - INSTALL_LIBPNG=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LIBPNG}
      - INSTALL_IONCUBE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IONCUBE}
      - PUID=${WORKSPACE_PUID}
      - PGID=${WORKSPACE_PGID}
      - CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION}
      - NODE_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_NODE_VERSION}
      - YARN_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_YARN_VERSION}
      - DRUSH_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_DRUSH_VERSION}
      - TZ=${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
      - BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_ID=${BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_ID}
      - BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_TOKEN=${BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_TOKEN}
  volumes:
    - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}
  extra_hosts:
    - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
  ports:
    - "${WORKSPACE_SSH_PORT}:22"
  tty: true
  environment:
    - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=${PHP_IDE_CONFIG}
  networks:
    - frontend
    - backend
```

php-fpm:

`php-fpm:
      build:
        context: ./php-fpm
        args:
          - LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION=${PHP_VERSION}
          - LARADOCK_PHALCON_VERSION=${PHALCON_VERSION}
          - INSTALL_XDEBUG=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XDEBUG}
          - INSTALL_PHPDBG=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PHPDBG}
          - INSTALL_BLACKFIRE=${INSTALL_BLACKFIRE}
          - INSTALL_SSH2=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SSH2}
          - INSTALL_SOAP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SOAP}
          - INSTALL_IMAP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_IMAP}
          - INSTALL_MONGO=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MONGO}
          - INSTALL_AMQP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_AMQP}
          - INSTALL_MSSQL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MSSQL}
          - INSTALL_ZIP_ARCHIVE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_ZIP_ARCHIVE}
          - INSTALL_BCMATH=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_BCMATH}
          - INSTALL_GMP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_GMP}
          - INSTALL_PHPREDIS=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PHPREDIS}
          - INSTALL_MEMCACHED=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MEMCACHED}
          - INSTALL_OPCACHE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_OPCACHE}
          - INSTALL_EXIF=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_EXIF}
          - INSTALL_AEROSPIKE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_AEROSPIKE}
          - AEROSPIKE_PHP_REPOSITORY=${AEROSPIKE_PHP_REPOSITORY}
          - INSTALL_MYSQLI=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MYSQLI}
          - INSTALL_PGSQL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PGSQL}
          - INSTALL_PG_CLIENT=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PG_CLIENT}
          - INSTALL_INTL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_INTL}
          - INSTALL_GHOSTSCRIPT=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_GHOSTSCRIPT}
          - INSTALL_LDAP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_LDAP}
          - INSTALL_PHALCON=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PHALCON}
          - INSTALL_SWOOLE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SWOOLE}
          - INSTALL_IMAGE_OPTIMIZERS=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_IMAGE_OPTIMIZERS}
          - INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK}
          - INSTALL_CALENDAR=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_CALENDAR}
          - INSTALL_FAKETIME=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_FAKETIME}
          - INSTALL_IONCUBE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_IONCUBE}
      volumes:
        - ./php-fpm/php${PHP_VERSION}.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
        - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}
      expose:
        - "9000"
      extra_hosts:
        - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
      environment:
        - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=${PHP_IDE_CONFIG}
        - DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker-in-docker:2375
        - FAKETIME=${PHP_FPM_FAKETIME}
      depends_on:
        - workspace
      networks:
        - backend
      links:
        - docker-in-docker`

postgres:

```
postgres:
      image: postgres:latest
      ports:
        - "${POSTGRES_PORT}:${POSTGRES_PORT}"
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
        - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      networks:
        - backend
```

pgadmin4:

```
    pgadmin:
  build: ./pgadmin
  ports:
    - "5050:5050"
  volumes:
    - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/pgadmin-backup:/var/lib/pgadmin/storage/pgadmin4
  depends_on:
    - postgres
  networks:
    - frontend
    - backend
```

nginx:

```
    nginx:
  build:
    context: ./nginx
    args:
      - PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER=${NGINX_PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER}
      - PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT=${NGINX_PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT}
      - CHANGE_SOURCE=${CHANGE_SOURCE}
  volumes:
    - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}
    - ${NGINX_HOST_LOG_PATH}:/var/log/nginx
    - ${NGINX_SITES_PATH}:/etc/nginx/sites-available
    - ${NGINX_SSL_PATH}:/etc/nginx/ssl
  ports:
    - "${NGINX_HOST_HTTP_PORT}:80"
    - "${NGINX_HOST_HTTPS_PORT}:443"
  depends_on:
    - php-fpm
  networks:
    - frontend
    - backend
```

python:

python:
      build:
        context: ./python-socket
      ports:
        - "9095:9095"
      volumes:
        - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}

**Given that I have sftp access & ssh access to the server, how to deploy and develop this project? Isn't there any simple way to deploy the project to the server and do fast code updates for testing purposes?**